# Which is more accurate for use of distance calculation on Lat/Long

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, distance

I need to calculate the distance between two points (Lat/Lng).
In android I can achieve this in two ways :

1)

```
location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

2)

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(location1, location2);
```

Which one should I use to get the most accurate distance between the two points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html) returns `double`, whereas [Location.distanceTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) returns `float`.

From documentation of `distanceTo`

> Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location.

From documentation of `computeDistanceBetween`

> Returns the distance between two LatLngs, in meters.

`SphericalUtil` tends to be more precise.